# Cartesian Product of Sets where No Elements are Identical under Permutations in Python

Tags: python, list, set, combinatorics

I have some sets I would like to take the Cartesian product of, which is working well. However, I want to remove all elements of this new set which are identical under a permutation of the elements.

For example, take the following code:

```
import itertools as ittools
x = 2
y = 3
z = 5

flist = list(ittools.product([x,y,z],repeat=3))

for f in flist:
    print reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, f)
```

This code find the Cartesian product of the set {2,3,5} and returns the product of all three components of each element in the resulting set. However, some numbers appear multiple times, i.e. 12 can be written as 2*2*3, 2*3*2, or 3*2*2. I would like to remove all but one instance of these duplicates.

I know that this fundamentally a combinatorics problem, but this seems like there is probably a nice solution in Python that doesn't involve doing an extra pass over the list like I did here to compute some identifier for each element of the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), not `product`:

```
itertools.combinations_with_replacement([x, y, z], 3)
```

Comment: I will give this a shot when I get home. From the function name this sounds like you might be right, it's what I want.

Comment: This is precisely the type of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` to map each unique product to the most recently seen tuple.

```
d = {reduce(operator.mul, f): f for f in flist}
```

If you would need to treat tuples that aren't permutations of each other as distinct elements, you'll need a more complicated key that incorporates a canonical representation of the tuple.

```
from operator import mul
d = {(tuple(sorted(f)), reduce(mul, f)): f for f in flist}
```

Actually, once you do that, you don't need to map the tuple/product pair to a tuple; you can just maintain a set of pairs:

```
d = {(tuple(sorted(f)), reduce(mul, f)) for f in flist}
```

In any case, retrieving just the tuples is as simple as

```
tuples = d.values()  # In the first two cases
tuples = {x for x,y in d} # In the third case
```

Comment: But this still uses all of the tuples.

Comment: Oops, I meant to use the product as the key, so that later tuples with the same product would replace the previously seen tuples.

Comment: I had imagined that was what you meant, but this would give wrong results when non-matching combinations give the same product e.g. `product([1,2,3,4], repeat=3)` , `(1,3,4)` and `(2,2,3)`.

Comment: Good point. It's not clear if the user wants to treat, say, `(1,4,6)` and `(2,3,4)` from `product(range(1,7), repeat=4)` as equivalent or not. (I clearly interpreted them as being equivalent.). One could use `(frozenset(f), reduce(mul, f))` as the key instead.

Comment: Ok. However, the `frozenset` will take out dupes. Sorry for being pedantic.

Comment: Ugh, right. (Pedantic is good here, I'm making too many quick assumptions.) `(sorted(tuple(f)), reduce(mul, f))`, I guess.

Comment: Yep, that would do :)

Comment: 1,4,6 should be distinct from 2,3,4. I specifically chose 2,3,5 in my example because they are all prime, so the product of any tuple will be identify the constituent elements. The actual code isn't dealing with ints, so the "product" is really a stand in for some commutative operation on all elements of the tuple.